# getting raw json string use jquery ajax method meet problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I use jquery ajax method, set datatype json, I get a jsonp response from a cross-domain server. But what i want is raw string of json response. so i set datatype text, but i got nothing but a empty string.

```
      $.ajax({
        url:"http://api.douban.com/book/subject/isbn/9787802057388?alt=xd&callback=?",
        dataType:'text',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        } //endof success
    }); //endof .ajax
```

can any one tell me why?
if use getJSON method to do this, how can i get a raw string of json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `dataType` to `text` prevents jQuery handling the request as a JSONP. jQuery does some magic in the background for these type of requests (substituting `callback=?` in the URL for a function name, and defining the `success` function as a global function).

Why do you want the response to be raw text? It isn't possible to get a response that is **just** JSON from a JSONP request, because the nature of JSONP requires the response is wrapped in a function call.

Setting the `dataType` to `jsonp` works, but of course an object is returned.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://api.douban.com/book/subject/isbn/9787802057388?alt=xd&callback=?",
    dataType:'jsonp',
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    } //endof success
}); //endof .ajax​​​​
```

If you want a string, you could double-json-encode a part of the response on the server, so that it is received as a string, or use a JavaScript JSON encoder on the client and encode it again, but both don't really seem ideal solutions. An object is much more usable and useful.

Comment: the reason is i want get a cross-domain jsonp response and sent it to my web server again.
To avoid jquery handle response as json, i change .getJSON to .ajax, so do you mean jquery ignore datatype field to handle the respons?

Comment: @elprup: In which case, the client should AJAX your server, who should retrieve the information from the remote domain, before returning a response. No, I mean that jQuery needs the `dataType` set to `jsonp` to correctly prepare the request to act as a `JSONP` request.

Comment: OK. The url I request has limit on request per IP, so i just want client to fetch the infomation for the server.

Comment: Here's an example where it's not more usable or useful: a programmer asks me -- what kind of stuff does that API return?  Okay, I say, I'll make them a page that makes a bunch of API calls and just sticks the raw responses onto the page so they can see what data is returned.  Oh wait -- I can't access the raw response.  I have to write a function that iterates through the members of the JSON object that is returned.

Comment: That's because an object is returned. Use `console.log(data)`, open your console, and you'll be able to see which properties exist on the object that you can use.